# Is there any mocking framework that allows to mock std::ifstream and other I/O libraries?

Tags: c++, testing, mocking

I work on a really old C++ project which has a huge DB I need to mock.
I am trying to mock ifstream library in order to test the control on files, the problem is that I can't change my legacy code so i am having a hard time finding the abilty to mock without changing  any piece of the code
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried GMock?

Comment: afaik, gmock only works on virtual methods.

Comment: does the function you're testing take an `ifstream&` argument or an `istream&` argument?

Comment: @selbie you are right, Gmock works only on virtual methods which are unfortunately not an option for me as i am not able to refactor any piece of my code

Comment: @RichardHodges ifstream& argument

Comment: given that ifstream is unlikely to be faulty, can't you just supply ifstreams with test files already opened?

Answer (score 1):

Mocking uses polymorphism (implements a given interface), so there are two choices:

- use dynamic polymorphism when the library offers the option. For ifstream, this is not the case AFAIK.
- use static polymorphism (templates), meaning that the legacy library offers the options to use something else than if stream.

I don't think your legacy application offers any of these options, so you will have to test it without mocks for now.